# How to debug the Magento's block caches

Tags: php, caching, magento

I asked myself how I can debug the block caches of Magento. I want to know which block is cached and how long is it cached?

For example there is a functionality under System > Configuration > Developer > Debug > [...] Hints. If I turn on this options I receive all the block names and their included template. I just want the same for the caching. I would like to know, which block, if it is cached or not, which cache id and how long it caches the block.

Does anybody has an idea or maybe a solution?

An idea would be enough to start :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`$block->getData('cache_lifetime');` should return the number of seconds the block is to be cached.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput